# How do I connect a database to a website so that the user can access the database and make changes to it?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am trying to make a website that allows the user to make changes to their individual mysql database. The website is written in PHP. How do I connect one of the web pages to a database? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

[phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) will do this, a logged on user will only see the databases they have access to.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/), I find that **[SQL Buddy](http://www.sqlbuddy.com/)** has a very clean, simple interface to work with.